# jquery Display datepicker when inline editing

Tags: jquery, datepicker, inline-editing

I'm doing inline editing on a table and I'm having an issuer with one of the cell which has to display datepicker when user clicks inside. 
when I click in the cell, the editing textbox is displax but when I click in the textbox, the datepicker doesn't appear. Thanks for your help.
Cheers

```
  $('.editable').live({
          hover: function () {
              //alert('Am hovering');
              //change background of an editable element if mouse hover
              $(this).toggleClass('over-inline');
          },
          click: function (e) {
           //start inline editing
              var $editable = $(this);

              if ($editable.hasClass('active-inline')) {
                  return;
              }
              var contents = $.trim($editable.html());
              initialValue = contents;
              var itemID = $editable.attr('id');
              var editID = 0;
              var s = '';
               $editable
                  .addClass('active-inline')
                  .empty();

                  //define the edit element
                  var editElement = '<input type="text" class="showDatePicker" />';
                  displayDatePicker('.showDatePicker');
                  $(editElement)
                    .val(initialValue)
                    .appendTo($editable)
                    .focus();
                  //addEditButtons($editable); function that add save/delete/cancel buttons
        }



      function displayDatePicker(selector) {

          $(selector).datepicker({
              showOn: "both",
              buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
              buttonImageOnly: true,
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true
          });
          $(selector).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'dd.mm.yy');
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the textbox class to Datepicker instead? like <input type="text" class="Datepicker">
So when you do $(".Datepicker").datepicker() your textbox will have the class "Datepicker hasDatepicker"

Comment: And by the way, try appending your textbox first and calling "displayDatePicker" afterwards!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I've just done that the datepicker now show but only when u click on the image that is display near the textbox. not directly when u click in the textbox
                       //define the edit element
                      var editElement = '<input type="text"  class="showDatePicker" />';
                      $(editElement)
                        .val(initialValue)
                        .appendTo($editable)
                        .focus();

                      displayDatePicker('.showDatePicker');

Comment: Edit your question and add your HTML code. Also try all the changes in my answer below.

Comment: Ok I just found the solution, I put the displayDatePicker inside as an argument of focus like this: $(editElement).focus(displayDatePicker('.showDatePicker')); Thanks for your help. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comments above, start by changing the order in which you do things:

- Append your newly created textbox;
- Call the function which will add the hasDatepicker class to the element;

Also change your textbox's class so it looks like this:

```
var editElement = '<input type="text" class="Datepicker" >';
```

Then you call the function this way:

```
displayDatePicker('.Datepicker');
```

Cheers